# Use KIF to swipe from screen edge (test UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)?

Tags: ios, kif, kif-framework

As of yet I have been unable to do a edge swipe in KIF (specifically running KIF tests against a device). Has anyone pulled this off? Am I missing something?

Resulting function:

```
func panInViewFromLeftScreenEdge() {
    // Grab the menu & its frame.
    let menuView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.subviews.last!
    let frame = menuView.bounds

    // Simulate a drag from the left edge to the right edge.
    let startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))
    let endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))

    menuView.dragFromPoint(startPoint, toPoint: endPoint)
}
```

Comment: Was able to make `menuView` generic by referencing the current frontmost view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
let view = tester().waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("<The view controller on screen's view's accessibility label")
view.dragFromPoint(CGPoint(x: 1, y: 150), toPoint: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 150))")
```

Comment: "<The view controller on screen's view's accessibility label>"
^ That was the key thing for me. I was working with the label of the view I wanted to show. Thanks!